# Anaconda PackagesNotFoundError when installing habitat-lab on Windows 11

Tags: windows, github, anaconda, conda, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to install habitat-lab for some experimentation from this [Github Repo](https://github.com/facebookresearch/habitat-lab#installation).

On the **instruction 2**, when I am putting the command:

```
conda install habitat-sim withbullet -c conda-forge -c aihabitat
```

I am getting following errors:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - habitat-sim

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/aihabitat/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/aihabitat/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/loopbio/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/loopbio/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: always use the search function on anaconda.org. There you can clearly see supported OS version. See [here](https://anaconda.org/aihabitat/habitat-sim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So according to [this issue on Github](https://github.com/facebookresearch/habitat-sim/issues/1570), they have no support for Windows OS.